# How to authenticate to a remote server using a remote server's local user via Powershell WinRM

Tags: powershell, winrm

Please consider the following scenario:

There are 2 servers: `server1` and `server2`, both on the same network and on the same domain. The objective is to open a PSSession from `server1` into `server2` using a local user from `server2` as the identity:

```
PS @SERVER1 > $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential server2\username
```

The local user on `server2` is a member of the `WinRMRemoteWMIUsers_` group

If a domain user is used then all works fine:

```
PS @SERVER1 > $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential domain\username
```

The error obtained when trying to connect as a local user is:

```
New-PSSession : [server2] Connecting to remote server server2 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos
    authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
     Possible causes are:
      -The user name or password specified are invalid.
      -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
      -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
      -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
      -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
     After checking for the above issues, try the following:
      -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
      -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
     Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
       -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

From the error message there is `The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication` and `-Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.` so, a connection was attempted after executing the following on server1:

```
PS @SERVER1 > winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="server2"}'
```

Attempting to start a `PSSession` after the command is executed still fails.

What other step can be attempted?

Comment: instead of `-Credential server2\username` try `-Credential (get-credential)`. -Credential (should) never accepts a dom\username or just username, it's looking for a pscredential object. @Roman is essentially building a pscredential object in his answer. If you want to reuse the credential object then store it in a var 
`$cred = get-credential` then feed it to the cmdlet: `-Crendential $cred`

[about Get-Credential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this

```
$cred = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("local credential", "Enter machine\user ID and password.", "localhost\$env:username", "")
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName server2 -Credential $cred
```

So, gather the credential first, then just plug it in. And, you can literally use localhost for the domain side and that works. Worked for me.

```
> $session
Id Name            ComputerName    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
-- ----            ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
1 Session1         server2         Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available
```